# I am getting a wrong output for numpy.sum

Tags: python, numpy

I have the variable X of the type numpy.ndarray

```
X = 
[[ 0.44381946  0.27899923  0.4949196 ]
 [ 0.84257149  0.30482022  0.62306499] 
 [ 0.59696025  0.36293078  0.42723482]
 [ 0.85710666  0.61489953  0.58918237]
 [ 0.99383178  0.88306841  0.85875682]]
```

When I use numpy.sum(X , axis=1) to sum along the columns, I get this as output

```
 [-2.7922436  -1.83243432 -2.37986939 -1.16950882 -0.28280943]
```

which is clearly wrong (there are no negative numbers in X). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: X is not a valid list/array. You need to seperate the elements from each other with a comma. The output I get is: `array([ 1.21773829,  1.7704567 ,  1.38712585,  2.06118856,  2.73565701])`

Comment: @ayhan where did the neg come from?

Comment: I don't know actually. Since the provided input will raise a syntax error, it's hard to guess without seeing the actual input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is defined incorrectly. You need commas between the elements on each line and also a comma between the numbers in each array row. See below for the proper syntax.

**Python (saved in file numpyArray.py)**

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[ 0.44381946,  0.27899923,  0.4949196 ],
              [ 0.84257149,  0.30482022,  0.62306499], 
              [ 0.59696025,  0.36293078,  0.42723482],
              [ 0.85710666,  0.61489953,  0.58918237],
              [ 0.99383178,  0.88306841,  0.85875682]])

print(np.sum(X,axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
> python -i numpyArray.py 
>>> [1.21773829  1.7704567   1.38712585  2.06118856  2.73565701]
```